# Why is Heroku sending me back data but my frontend is not rendering anything?

Tags: heroku, axios, mern

I deployed my backend to Heroku and it deployed successfully. I've connected the frontend to the backend using Axios and have changed the baseURL from localhost to the Heroku one but once I open up the app, nothing shows up besides raw json data.

Answer (score 0):

you must have a manifest.json in you front end folder and it must have start "start_url" pointed to index.js just like below..

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/logo.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.js",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```